# ssh using private key fails: server accepts key, still getting return packet type 51: access denied (public key)

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

People in my organization connects to their GitHub repo over ssh key. Recently, some people are getting :permission denied (public key)

The issue is not only with GitHub, they are not able to connect to any other devices over ssh key.

I added verbose upto three level, and found out that Server accepts the key, still I'm getting packet return type 51.

Other people (on the internet) having similar issues do not get **Server accepts the key**.

Even I do not have any permission related issues.

I've gone through several stackoverflow related questions and other blogs too. But, no one has this unique issue when Server accepts the key, still the return packet type is 51.

These affected machines are not able to ssh to any server over key. Not even EC2, or local server, or GitHub authentication.

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: id_rsa RSA SHA256:JGTSrwZA4qP6vzxrQ3THqcPl6v4m2y3skwqHnm80ic4 explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: id_rsa RSA SHA256:JGTSrwZA4qP6vzxrQ3THqcPl6v4m2y3skwqHnm80ic4 explicit agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with RSA SHA256:JGTSrwZA4qP6vzxrQ3THqcPl6v4m2y3skwqHnm80ic4
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:JGTSrwZA4qP6vzxrQ3THqcPl6v4m2y3skwqHnm80ic4
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

**Edit1:**
Output after unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: id_rsa RSA SHA256:JGTSrwZA4qP6vzxrQ3THqcPl6v4m2y3skwqHnm80ic4 explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: id_rsa RSA SHA256:JGTSrwZA4qP6vzxrQ3THqcPl6v4m2y3skwqHnm80ic4 explicit
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with RSA SHA256:JGTSrwZA4qP6vzxrQ3THqcPl6v4m2y3skwqHnm80ic4
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:JGTSrwZA4qP6vzxrQ3THqcPl6v4m2y3skwqHnm80ic4
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

Comment: What happens if a) the affected machine is rebooted, or b) the user does `unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK` before trying to ssh (to bypass the running 'ssh-agent')?

Comment: @u1686_grawity I've edited the question to include the output after unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK. It is still same. Even I've tried rebooting the affected machines, as well as rebooting sshd.service and ssh.service. Nothing helped. I even tried reinstalling openssh-client and openssh-server on the affected machines. But the issue still persists.

Comment: Hi @u1686_grawity I'm still getting the same issue. Is it possible for you to look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this issue was solved after reinstalling openssh client package.

> sudo apt install --reinstall openssh-client

**Note:** Do not uninstall and then install the package. Uninstalling openssh-client will also uninstall snapd, resulting in broken snap packages (if you have installed any). Better solution is to use the reinstall flag.